# Connection pool performance in java

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling

How to practically check the performance of different connection pools in java.I tried closing and opening connections in for-loop but I found no difference in performance all were finishing 10000 iterations almost at same time. Can someone give me programmatic code to analyse the performance differences of various pools

Answer (score 1):

According to official documentation:

> `acquireIncrement` Determines how many connections at a time c3p0 will
> try to acquire when the pool is exhausted.

setAcquireIncrement() sets this value with an integer:

```
void setAcquireIncrement(int acquireIncrement)
                     throws javax.naming.NamingException
```

More details here https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/